# why I can't get total number of pages on output after using 'num_pages' property of pagination in django

Tags: python, django, pagination

where i made mistake... why I can't able to get total  number of pages on output

[code which giving error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf3mU.png)

Comment: Pls don't share code in images, instead write it out in snippets

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.